# Laravel package namespace can't find controller composer 2

Tags: php, laravel

I've recently updated my custom Laravel package's namespace after my original [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67517227/class-does-not-comply-with-psr-4-autoloading-standard-composer-2-warning-laravel) was closed, I've followed the suggestion from the attached answers in my original question and just need some pointers here.

Composer 1 throws a warning regarding my class, so I've gone ahead and updated my namespace to be lowercase since, and most of the warnings have gone away in terms of the controllers, but now, when I run `composer dump` my error is that:

> Target class [company\mypackage\ApplyController] does not exist.

Previously, my class had uppercase letters:

> namespace Company\MyPackage;

and my folders `http` and `controllers` had an uppercase letter, they're now lowercase and I don't know why I'm getting an error now?

The full error now is:

```
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException 

  Target class [company\mypackage\ApplyController] does not exist.

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:835
    831▕ 
    832▕         try {
    833▕             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    834▕         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
  ➜ 835▕             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
    836▕         }
    837▕ 
    838▕         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
    839▕         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is

      +6 vendor frames 
  7   /Users/user/Sites/laravel-packages/mypackage/src/MyPackageServiceProvider.php:18
      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::make("company\mypackage\ApplyController")

      +7 vendor frames 
  15  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Comment: Can you share your composer.json (or at least the autoloading part)?

Comment: Looks like I've been missin the `Models` inside of models for name spapcing, e.g: `namespace Company\MyPackage\Models`, adding this and the same for Controllers etc seems to fix it